# GCC attribute to silent uninitialised variable warning

Tags: c, gcc

Just as there is the `__unused__` attribute, I wonder if there is any attribute to let the compiler know I know what I'm doing by not initialising a variable and then (from compiler's perspective) doing operations on it (which is false).
If you want to know more, the code:

```c
static void net_avl_balance(struct net_avl_tree* const tree, uint32_t idx) {
  struct net_avl_node* node;
  struct net_avl_node* parent;
  struct net_avl_node* temp;
  uint32_t child = 0; // the problem right there, set to 0 to silent the warning
  do {
    // bubble up and check stuff. "child" is only used when a rotation is needed,
    // and rotation is never needed when checking the leaf node, so it is not a problem
    // that it is uninitialised.
    child = idx; // ensures that it is initialised when rotation occurs
    idx = node->parent;
  } while(/* parent exists */);
}
```

Completely understandable that GCC 9.2.1 is not willing to spend so much time thinking if the leaf node will require using unitialised `child` or not. I also am aware of possible solutions to the problem, but I just want to hear about attributes. Thanks.
reprex:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
 
enum net_avl_flags { avl_balanced, avl_left, avl_right };
 
struct net_avl_node {
  uintptr_t value;
  uint32_t parent;
  uint32_t left;
  uint32_t right;
  int sfd;
};
 
struct net_avl_part {
  struct net_avl_node* items;
  uint32_t amount;
};
 
struct net_avl_tree {
  struct net_avl_part* parts;
  uint32_t count;
  uint32_t amount;
  uint32_t max_items_per_part;
  uint32_t head;
};
 
void net_avl_balance(struct net_avl_tree* const tree, uint32_t idx) {
  struct net_avl_node* node;
  struct net_avl_node* parent;
  struct net_avl_node* temp;
  uint32_t child;
  do {
    node = &tree->parts[idx / tree->max_items_per_part].items[idx % tree->max_items_per_part];
    parent = &tree->parts[node->parent / tree->max_items_per_part].items[node->parent % tree->max_items_per_part];
    switch(parent->value & 3) {
      case avl_left: {
        if(idx == parent->left) {
          if(child == node->right) {
            temp = &tree->parts[node->right / tree->max_items_per_part].items[node->right % tree->max_items_per_part];
            parent->left = node->right; // required so that it doesn't optimise this away using -O3
            /* ... */
          }
          /* ... */
        }
        return;
      }
      /* ... */
    }
    child = idx;
    idx = node->parent;
  } while(parent->parent != UINT32_MAX);
}
 
int main() {
  struct net_avl_tree tree = (struct net_avl_tree) {
    .parts = NULL,
    .amount = 0,
    .max_items_per_part = 0,
    .head = 0
  };
  net_avl_balance(&tree, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile using `-O3 -Wall` flags.

Comment: Can you construct a [mcve] that reproduces the warning?

Comment: I don't think there is such an attribute. The gcc manual mentions using things like `assert(0);` to suppress -Wmaybe-uninitialized warnings by telling the compiler that some branches (like those where the variable doesn't get initialized) are unreachable, but in my experience this sometimes doesn't work with clang and only an initialization will suppresses the warning (you can also disable the warning).

Comment: [Here.](https://pastebin.com/GYiBpG4W) @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @FranciszekBalcerak The code should be in the question not off-site link in comments.  However in this case the example is not "minimal".

Comment: In order to reproduce the warning it is necessary to know what warning options you are using.

Comment: The warning options are specified within the code, at the bottom, next to `int main() {` as a comment. And okay, I will include it in the post.  
Also, why do you think it's not minimal?

Comment: "Minimal" would be the least amount of code that produces the warning you wish to suppress. Also the original fragment (that remains in the question) does not generate `warning: ‘child’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]  ` because of the line `child = idx;`.  It is the line `if(child == node->right)` in the second posted code that causes the warning.  Your "not minimal" code also generates other warnings that are just a distraction from your question.

Comment: `int main()
{
    int child ;
    if( child = 0 ) ;
}` is minimal.

Comment: Why not just initialise it?

Comment: The question is not asking to help me get rid of the warning, but an attribute to silence it. Leave whether or not to initialise it to me, please. And also, the reprex I gave, if ran with GCC 9.2.1 and `-O3 -Wall` flags, should only output one warning, which is the question's warning. If it does otherwise for you, you should consider your methods wrong, not mine. Otherwise, please prove me wrong.

Comment: Additionally, the problem I am describing is not as simple as your minimal code states. It involves knowledge whether or not the leaf node can be rotated or not (and it can't). Your code is simplifying the problem, potentially yielding a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively the line:

```
(void)child;
```

Will suppress warnings for unused `child`

Comment: It is not unused. It is used, but the compiler doesn't realise it is initialised after the potential place where it could be used (and it is not), yielding unexpected result.